# {"error":"Unauthenticated."} Laravel 5.3 Personal Access tokens

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

The error is only occurring when personal access tokens are being used, If I use a Password client to get a token then it goes through fine.

This is the Route that I'm using to test that it is going through

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return "hello";
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

This is the function that I am using to get the access token

```
public function testToken() {
    $user = User::where("id", 12)->first();

    $token = $user->createToken("TokenName")->accessToken;

    return $token;
}
```

This is the access token that I'm trying to use (The one gotten from `testToken()`)

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjNlNTliODI1ZWVlZTYzZjRkMjYxZTliMDRiZTdlOGM2OTE2OGIxODIzOWVhZDQ3YjkwODY0ZGQxODU2ZmZkYjc1NmNiNzE2NTRjOGQ1N2U0In0.eyJhdWQiOiI1IiwianRpIjoiM2U1OWI4MjVlZWVlNjNmNGQyNjFlOWIwNGJlN2U4YzY5MTY4YjE4MjM5ZWFkNDdiOTA4NjRkZDE4NTZmZmRiNzU2Y2I3MTY1NGM4ZDU3ZTQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTk3NzA4ODgsIm5iZiI6MTQ5OTc3MDg4OCwiZXhwIjoxODE1MzAzNjg4LCJzdWIiOiIxMiIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.TkAanA7Un5Z4BHYVm1tBUtzQXDNl_z26fHcbzC-wNC-7zHg3GCqnWicgKxZsuE5_1zuDikqZj6tKKkRou5K2ftA9A6l3wBMxmyQZy-BZl20CbzyovYw5kfFwOdJYNKeAF5g0jBVXJdFCDvHexiQGrfzoj9b95v9jRNfdDbhrJd-1wHMQpIps7qjn3rtVIupwc2HpajJ4hADgZUCGjcV8YpOpWoaTt8lZocJUlUTbeNE0AwdI_c9tSA48qaSZizOIb1DYLSLZjeqKvRJFHvplAhTQN9glbF598Nws0FqkvnEWk-3nXL8EejJ155EAyNwKkDnc3e6W23JqjdGzXiHsTRmVDdizLrkk86Z-24oj2KJwcdPYMGkcnggqIZ8hn7ikGSoTV73G_nW_VUBOidHzcYKgMgXPQGST2gC3yPgAnQJPmXBUyc98hMz4LbDNkXKYcsMp23kUxC1caO3JYE4LljVLaQaxdhqZlaTBcaus5HtcRYrYMmZhgxaXpy-VOM2fljBW-QgM1rs8D9GwBuxecBmgPvbN6HqnYTlYRwmxbfOtKoeT7H5aK3_a36at1dL1V3K0S176v91ZGfWoxlYLzq_uWxpq_T9SOkaoxjeMfYiVjJyXMDsTbmE7PrQQcEwKNVc9DdcQgJmewd-Sr15O66inhH8j7-4_WPysxS6SXBY
```

I'm passing the token through in the header (**NOTE** I'm testing using postman)

```
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer **TOKEN**
```

Doing some Googling I found that people have fixed it by setting the expiration date of the token, Though this did not work in my case.

I also found people suggesting to change Passport.php in the providers, but I do not have this file to edit... I don't know if it could be because I installed passport wrong or something like that. I did follow the documentation for the install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you will read the document carefully and the problem will be solved.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#installation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens

This route creates new personal access tokens. It requires two pieces of data: the token's name and the scopes that should be assigned to the token:

```js
const data = {
    name: 'Token Name',
    scopes: []
};

axios.post('/oauth/personal-access-tokens', data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.accessToken);
    })
    .catch (response => {
        // List errors on response...
    });
```

Comment: Not exactly, I did read through them... And passport its self is working, as well as being able to get an access token... But when I pass the token through, event though I use the same method with password tokens, It still comes back "unauthenticated".

Comment: @TheMysticalWarrior get the token through Token Name?

Comment: Sorry bud, your phrasing has me a bit confused ... xD

Comment: I have just tested a new version and everything is ok and it is recommended that you check the config / auth.php and User.php if they made special changes

Comment: Yes found the problem... using 2 tables for authentication... So it's trying to find information that doesn't exist in that table... At least I know what the problem is now xD